# Apache Solr UI connection refused

Tags: apache-http-server

Trying to get the UI for Solr in my browser and keep getting "This webpage is not available....err_connection_refused".

I've installed several times on other systems with no problem.

Running Ubuntu 14.04, php, Mariadb - there is no website installed, nothing in the database, the Solr Status looks good - it's running on port :8983.

I've stopped, started, Solr (it's setup as a service - but I've re-installed it, fresh, and not have it start as a service and started it manually) and Apache2, rebooted - Apache2 is running fine, PHP is good - I can see the testphp.php I created.

But when I go to the domain - and you'all can check it out if you like - there's no security on it - just a test bed - hitsolr.cloudapp.net:8983/solr  - it just doesn't work.

Knowing myself, I'm missing something simple? lol The only difference between this server and others, where I had it working, is this is a brand new config and there was nothing on it. I did the updates, installed the dependencies - it's running! I just can't get into the UI.

Anybody?

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: There is one other difference - I downloaded this package from "OpenSemanticSearch.com" - it's supposedly pre-configured and good to go. But the one thing I did notice is that it installed in /opt/solr-5.0.0/ and created a link /opt/solr - which links to solr-5.0.0    ....   I tried renaming the 5.0.0 to solr, but it didn't have any impact.

Comment: If you telnet to it, is it responding? Like: `telnet localhost 8983`? In other words check if something is listening on that port via: `sudo netstat -nap | grep 8983`. If not, maybe it's listening on different port, like 8080?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - it was working fine on 8983 - I could access Solr UI no problem, load a core, etc…it's the Open Semantic Search - none of their downloads are quite at 100% it seems. They have a "server" image - but it's missing all the Python Libs, incorrect Java and such. So I started from scratch with just Solr and no 3rd party extensions.

Comment: Are you running it on Tomcat or Jetty? It could work on 8983, but only on localhost, so check your listening address ip. What is the results of the commands which I've send to you? For example netstat, do you have `127.0.0.1:8983` or `0.0.0.0:8983`?